# Failing to draw polygrams?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

Here is a class that draws stars, as part of Chapter 13 Exercise 19 of *Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Programming: Principles and Practice*.

> Class `Star` uses *penta-, hexa-, hepta-* and *octa-gram* as basis together with a property (rotational symmetry) that stars with multiple vertices (10, 12, 14, 18, etc) have, to draw n-grams<sup>1</sup>:

`Chapter13Exercise19.cpp`

```
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Chapter13Exercise19.h"

int main(){
     // window parameters
     int winWidth = 800;
     int winHeight = 600;
     Point centerPoint((x_max() - winWidth) / 2, (y_max() - winHeight) / 2);
     Simple_window* siw = new Simple_window(centerPoint, winWidth,
                                            winHeight, "Chapter 13 Exercise 19");

 try{
     Point center(siw->x_max()/2, siw->y_max()/2);
     int radius = 150;
     // Currenly: sides > 5, sides =! 13, 17, 19 and multiples
     int sides = 16;

     Graph_lib::Star st(center, radius, sides);
     siw->attach(st);
     siw->wait_for_button();
 }catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    getchar();
 }catch(const std::invalid_argument& e){ 
     cerr << e.what() << endl;
     getchar();
 }catch(...){
    cerr <<"Defaul exception!"<< endl;
    getchar();
 }

}
```

`Chapter13Exercise19.h`

```
#ifndef _Chapter13Exercise19_H_
#define _Chapter13Exercise19_H_
#define PI 3.14159265359

namespace Graph_lib{
class Star: public Lines{
public:
    Star(Point c, int r, int n);
private:
    int vertexNumber;
    Point center;
    int radius;
    vector<Point>starCoordinates;
    // parameters kept as function recursive
    void rotateCoordinate(Point& axisOfRotation, Point& initial, 
                          double angRads, int numberOfRotations);
    void generatePoly();
    void makeStar();
};
#include "Chapter13Exercise19Def.cpp"
} // end of namespace Graph_lib

#endif
```

`Chapter13Exercise19Def.cpp`

```
// Class Members implementation
Star::Star(Point c, int r, int n)
    : vertexNumber(n), center(c), radius(r)
{ 
    if(n < 5) throw std::invalid_argument("Not enough verteces!");
    generatePoly(); 
    makeStar();
}

void Star::rotateCoordinate(Point& axisOfRotation, Point& initial,
                            double angRads, int numberOfRotations){
    if(numberOfRotations <= 0) return;
    else{
        double x = cos(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x)
                 - sin(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.x;
        double y = sin(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x) 
                 + cos(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.y;
        starCoordinates.push_back(Point(x, y));
        rotateCoordinate(axisOfRotation, Point(x,y), angRads, --numberOfRotations);
    }
}

void Star::generatePoly(){ 
    double angRads = (PI / 180.) * (360. / vertexNumber);
    Point initial(center.x, center.y - radius);
    rotateCoordinate(center, initial, angRads, vertexNumber);
}

void Star::makeStar(){
    // every if statement covers Star with n and multiples of n vertexes
    // the inner for loops execute one iteration for the fundamental stars
    // and n iterations for the multiples (rotational symmetry)
    if (vertexNumber % 5 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0; it < starCoordinates.size() / 5; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+3], starCoordinates[it]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it+2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+2], starCoordinates[it+4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+4], starCoordinates[it+1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+1], starCoordinates[it+3]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 3 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0; it < starCoordinates.size() / 3; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it+2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+2], starCoordinates[it+4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+4], starCoordinates[it]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 7 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0; it < starCoordinates.size() / 7; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it+3]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+3], starCoordinates[it+6]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+6], starCoordinates[it+2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+2], starCoordinates[it+5]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+5], starCoordinates[it+1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+1], starCoordinates[it+4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+4], starCoordinates[it]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 8 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0; it < starCoordinates.size() / 8; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it+5]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+5], starCoordinates[it+2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+2], starCoordinates[it+7]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+7], starCoordinates[it+4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+4], starCoordinates[it+1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+1], starCoordinates[it+6]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+6], starCoordinates[it+3]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it+3], starCoordinates[it]);
       }
   } else throw std::invalid_argument("Star vertexes'number not supported!");
}
```

### Result:

While all the basic polygrams (5,6,7,8 vertices) look as they should, in the cases of polygrams with vertices: 10, 12, 14 etc, I get these partly finished drawings.

[image]

I am aware that the problem comes from function `makeStar()` in `Chapter13Exercise19Def.cpp`, but I can't figure it out what the problem is.

### Question:

1. Why are the drawing coming partly drawn, what is wrong with the implementation of function `makeStar()`?
2. Is there another algorithm that can do similar job?

---

<sup>1. currently multiples of 5, 6, 7 and 8.</sup>

All the additional files for compilation could be found: [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/). The *FLTK* could be found [here](http://www.fltk.org/index.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really play with your code as it relies on that visualization library you're using, but I see what the problem is, and I'm pretty confident I know the solution.

The `rotateCoordinate` recursive function generates a vector of points, evenly spread along a bounding circle of your polygram, ordered in a clockwise direction.

When you then construct the lines that define (draw...) the polygram, you use the points, but you're not using to correct indices. For example, suppose you'd have a polygram {16/2} (2 hexagrams), you'd have 0-15 indexed points, but your `for` loop to generate the lines would at most reach index 8 (`it = 1`, index `[it + 7]`), and that's obviously wrong.

What you should be doing is multiply your constant numbers (the ones you add to `it`) by the number of polygons in your polygram, so in the case of {16/2} that would be 2.

Try this code:

```
void Star::makeStar(){
    // every if statement covers Star with n and multiples of n vertexes
    // the inner for loops execute one iteration for the fundamental stars
    // and n iterations for the multiples (rotational symmetry)
    if (vertexNumber % 5 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0, polygons = starCoordinates.size() / 5; it < polygons; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3], starCoordinates[it]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 6 == 0){ // for polygons multiples of 6
        size_t polygons = starCoordinates.size() / 6;
        for (size_t it = 0, ; it < starCoordinates() / 3; ++it){
            // generated by two triangles 
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4], starCoordinates[it]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 7 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0, polygons = starCoordinates.size() / 7; it < polygons; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 6]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 6], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 5]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 5], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4], starCoordinates[it]);
        }
    }else if (vertexNumber % 8 == 0){
        for (size_t it = 0, polygons = starCoordinates.size() / 8; it < polygons; ++it){
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 5]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 5], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 2], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 7]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 7], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 4], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 1], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 6]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 6], starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3]);
            Lines::add(starCoordinates[it + polygons * 3], starCoordinates[it]);
       }
   } else throw std::invalid_argument("Star vertexes'number not supported!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! All the needed files are included at the end of the question. Regarding the `for` loop: you are right, the second part of the coordinates are not accessed at all. Nice solution!

Comment: Does it actually work (as I expected)? If so, I'd appreciate an upvote :-)

Comment: All the votes for today are spent, it will be upvoted in 3 hours. For know only accepted :)

Comment: It works great: I've just put the expressions: `size_t polygons = starCoordinates.size() / 5` outside the for loop, right after the `if` statement.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, that's a typo from copy pasting :-) I had it outside originally. fixing.